# comment_form() not showing on custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, comment-form

I'm using *Gravity Forms* to create entries from forms, and *Gravity View* to display these entries on the Front-End.

By default, Gravity Forms and Gravity View doesn't have a comment system for the entries, so the idea is, creating a custom comment system.
I could do this easier, using custom post types to store and display entries as posts, having comments enabled, but Gravity Views has sorting, advanced search, display modes and such. So on the other side, it wouldn't benefit me, losing all those functions.

Submitting an entry creates a new "comment" post, storing the ID of the entry in a custom field (custom post type).

Under the entry I've got the assigned Post's comments being displayed so far.
The problem is, right now I can only add comments from the Back-End admin, the comment form is not showing on Front-End.

I've been trying to solve this, but I ran into another problem related to this.

Checking comments_open() for a specific "comment" post return false. For this, I just don't know why. I checked the database for comment_status, and it's "open" for every "comment" post.

```
comments_open(105);
```

**The entries' comment system is using a custom comments_template, based on comments.php, but only the comment display was changed, nothing radical.**

In the default comments.php file, it returns true.

I'm trying to display the comment form in this template (just like the original). The entry-page uses a different loop, so like when listing comments, I thought I'd need the "comment" post's ID to display its comment_form.

```
comment_form('','105');
```

I'm confused, because this code works smooth in the default comments.php file, showing (ID=105) Post's comment form. Using the same code in my custom comments template file, it shows nothing.

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Are you able to add comments for your custom post type from front-end using default `comments.php` and default `comment_form()`?